# how to create multidimensional array using a foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I take the form values in array

```
$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$job   = $_POST['job'];
$desc  = $_POST['desc'];
$photo = $_POST['image_url'];

$memberdata = Array(
          'first_name' => $fname,
          'last_name' => $lname,
          'job' => $job,
          'desc' => $desc,
          'image_url' => $photo
          );
```

and echoing this array it prints like below. 
How should the code be modified to achieve the goal?
Is there any other ways to get results what I want?
Member forms are dynamically generated using jquery.
And I want to get member vise array that I mentioned below.

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Member1
            [1] => Member2
            [2] => Member3
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Member1
            [1] => Member2
            [2] => Member3
        )

    [job] => Array
        (
            [0] => President
            [1] => MD
            [2] => CEO
        )

    [desc] => Array
        (
            [0] => President of
            [1] => MD of
            [2] => CEO of
        )

    [image_url] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

How to make particular array from above array?
How should the code be modified to achieve the goal?
 This is what i want.

```
 Array
(
   [0] => Array
   (
      [first_name] => Member1
      [last_name] => Member1
      [job] => President
      [desc] => President of
      [image_url] =>
   )

   [1] => Array
   (
      [first_name] => Member2
      [last_name] => Member2
      [job] => MD
      [desc] => MD of
      [image_url] =>
   )

   [2] => Array
   (
      [first_name] => Member3
      [last_name] => Member3
      [job] => CEO 
      [desc] => CEO of
      [image_url] =>
   )
)
```

Comment: Please add the `foreach` loop PHP code

Comment: And how did you tried to resolve this problem and didn't work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is your `foreach` loop looks like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($members as $member) {
    $result['firstname'][] = $member['firstname'];
    $result['last_name'][] = $member['last_name'];
    //etc
}
```

And it should be something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($members as $member) {
    $result[] = array(
        'firstname' => $member['firstname'],
        'last_name' => $member['last_name'],
        'job' => $member['job'],
        'desc' => $member['desc'],
        'image_url' => $member['image_url']
    );
}
```

**Update based on sample code:**

The POST fields are arrays, so you have to make sure all fields are posted for every member, as the `for` loop is based on all fields having the same amount of values.

```
$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
$job   = $_POST['job'];
$desc  = $_POST['desc'];
$photo = $_POST['image_url'];

$memberdata = array();

// we iterate the firstname field and access the same indexes from the other fields. The $i starts with 0 and gets incremented until it iterated over all the firstnames
for($i = 0; $i < count($fname); $i++) {
    $memberdata[] = array(
        'first_name' => $fname[$i], // we access the firstname at the current index
        'last_name' => $lname[$i],
        'job' => $job[$i],
        'desc' => $desc[$i],
        'image_url' => $photo[$i]
    );
}

var_dump($memberdata);
```

Comment: thanks @Tumtum, but its only shows that empty array without its values. I have edited my post, may be you can get any idea from that.